# Doubt in logic theory

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I  am a beginner in mathematical logic. I found following which i did not understand

**1) Addition logical implicative -**

$p \to (p \lor q)$
In explanation, he says if we know p, then we can add q. Then he says, we can know about p or q. I did not understand the intuition behind this. If p is true then when we add q(irrespective of true or false), we can say p or q is true. But when p is false, we can not know about p or q right?

Pls note that i can prove that the above is tautology

**2)Simplification -**

$(p \land q) \to p$ - in explanation he says if we know p and q then we can know about p. How? if p and q is true then we can say that p was true. But then if p and q is false, we can not say about p right?. Pls note that i can prove that the above is tautology

**3) Distributive law wrto implication**
I understood distributive law wrto and and or operators.
$p \to (q \land r) \iff (p \to q) \land (p \to r)$

**Do we have similar distributive law wrto following implication.**

Say $[p \lor (q \implies r)] \iff [(p \lor q) \implies (p \lor r)]$

Comment: If $p$ is false, then we *don't care* about $p\lor q$.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting "$\varphi \to \psi$" to mean "$\psi$ is true because of $\varphi$". This isn't what it means. It means "if $\varphi$ is true, then $\psi$ is true"—but it says nothing about the truth value of $\psi$ when $\varphi$ is false. So $p \to (p \vee q)$ means that if $p$ is true, then so is $p \vee q$; it doesn't say anything about whether $p \vee q$ is true or false in the case when $p$ is false.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  sir why they are called addition and simplification logical implicatives? i just want to know the intuition behind them. I understood what u r refering to ...

Comment: If you understand that, then you understand the intuition.

Comment: I  did not understand  .. pls elaborate again if possible ... else i will rethnk on this

Comment: Actually i was thinking from p how could theyhave derived p or q. From p and q how could they have derived p. I recently begun logic theory. Kindly elaborate 1 and 2 point ...

Comment: I'll try to explain from a different angle. To see why $p \rightarrow q$ is true when $p$ is false, suppose that I said: "If it rains, I will go to the movies". Then suppose that it doesn't rain, but I decided to go to the movies anyway. Did I lie? The answer is no, because I didn't say anything about what would happen if it _didn't_ rain. Since it didn't rain, my statement would have been true no matter what I did. So $p\rightarrow q$ is always true if $p$ is false. I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: They should **not** be called "addition" and "simplification", because those names make no sense whatsoever. You just need to grasp the recursive **definition** of the truth-values of boolean expressions, and forget about meaningless names.

Comment: thanks all. I understood now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In parts (1) and (2) You seem to be confusing material implication $A \rightarrow B$ with material equivalence $A \leftrightarrow B$.

$A \rightarrow B$ is true as long as it is not the case that $A$ is true and $B$ is false. In symbols:

$(A \rightarrow B) \leftrightarrow \lnot(A \land \lnot B)$

So if we know that $A$ is true and $A \rightarrow B$ then we can conclude that $B$ is true. But if we know that $A$ is false then $A \rightarrow B$ tells us nothing; $B$ can be either true or false.

On the other hand, $A \leftrightarrow B$ means that $A$ and $B$ have the same truth value.

For part (3) use a truth table. List the eight combinations of truth values for $p, q, r$ and evaluate $p \lor (q \rightarrow r)$ and $(p \lor q) \rightarrow (p \lor r)$ for each combination. If $p \lor (q \rightarrow r)$ and $(p \lor q) \rightarrow (p \lor r)$ always have the same truth value then $(p \lor (q \rightarrow r)) \leftrightarrow ((p \lor q) \rightarrow (p \lor r))$. If not then you have found a counterexample.

Comment: thank you sir.Got it now.